# Microsoft Graph update SharePoint list item multi choice field

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

What is the proper JSON syntax to update a multi-choice list item field using the Microsoft Graph?

Multi choice fields return a json array of strings like:

GET: `/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/lists/{listId}/items/{itemId}`

```
"CAG_x0020_Process_x0020_Status": [
    "Proposed Funding - Customer Billed",
    "Proposed Funding - Sales Funded",
    "SOW - Needed"
]
```

However, when using the same syntax to update the field a 400 invalid request is returned.

PATCH: `/v1.0/sites/{siteId}/lists/{listId}/items/{itemId}/fields`

```
"CAG_x0020_Process_x0020_Status": [
    "Proposed Funding - Customer Billed",
    "Proposed Funding - Sales Funded",
    "SOW - Needed"
]
```

Error returned:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "invalidRequest",
    "message": "The request is malformed or incorrect.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "2251e25f-e4ce-491f-beb9-e463c7d8d5af",
      "date": "2018-05-16T15:16:23"
    }
  }
}
```

I am able to update all other fields requested, but this last field is holding up a release of the application.

Answer (score 5):

To elaborate on what @muhammad-obaidullah-ather wrote in the comments, for string multiple choices you need to define the type as *Collection(Edm.**String**)* and then his solutions works for me. Repeating what he wrote as complete answer.
This should be sent as a PATCH like this:

```
PATCH /v1.0/sites/{SiteId}/lists/{ListId}/items/{ItemId}/fields

{"*FieldName*@odata.type":"Collection(Edm.String)","*FieldName*":["*Value1*","*Value2*"]}
```

Comment: This works for me at the time of making this comment. There's no word about it in the graph API docs.

Comment: This works for me, but the *'s wrapping the FieldName was tripping me up.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me

```
graph.api(url)
  .version('beta')
  .post({
    'fields': {
      'AssignedToLookupId@odata.type': 'Collection(Edm.Int32)',
      'AssignedToLookupId': [5,13]
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, a number of column types, including `MultiChoice`, cannot be updated via Microsoft Graph today. I would recommend adding this to the [Office Dev UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) so it remains on the radar of the SharePoint/Graph team.

Comment: its supported. you can do it like 

graph.api(url)
  .version('beta')
  .post({
    'fields': {
      "CAG_x0020_Process_x0020_Status@odata.type": "Collection(Edm.String)",
      "CAG_x0020_Process_x0020_Status": [ "Proposed Funding - Customer Billed", "Proposed Funding - Sales Funded", "SOW - Needed" ]
    }
  });